# How to put system in warm reboot using adb

Tags: java, android, python, python-2.7, adb

How can I put system in warm reboot using adb.

I can use 'adb reboot' to put it through cold reboot.

Comment: Define "warm reboot" in the context of Android.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use below mentioned command and also look the following link for more info http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2325378

## setprop ctl.restart zygote.....